# Proper way to switch 80 VDC for continous high current operation?

Tags: high-voltage, switching, electromagnet

I'm designing a circuit to change current direction for an electromagnet (57 Ω, 76.2 mH) which I drive with 80 V.

I have been using an H-bridge but due to the long on-state period (several seconds), the MOSFETs blow up.

I couldn't find (small) relays that could take such high DC voltage and I'm not sure if a thyristor would have the same problem as the MOSFETs.

Any ideas to solve this problem?

[image]

[edit] The H-bridge has not a switching purpose, a N-type MOSFET is placed after the H-bridge for the switching part.
The current flow is therefore cutted when the direction of the current must be switched. This allow for the H-bridge MOSFETs to turn on/off properly before the current flow.
I use SH8M51GZETB for the H-Bridge instead of the IRF7309

[edit] Constant current circuit
[image]

Comment: Are you sure the parts are failing due to the long on state, (over heating), or could it be the switching state that may create a very large flyback voltage?  Do you have protection diodes across each MOSFET?

Comment: Please show a schematic of your current circuit that blows up.

Comment: What MOSFETs are you actually using? IRF7309 on the schematic is a 30V part. If you're actually using these on 80V, well you have an answer.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. Yes, I have protection diodes. 
The circuit works fine until I drive the electromagnet at full power. Pd of the MOSFETs is 2W and I calculated that I'm around 0.5W.

Comment: Yeah, I couldn't find my parts on Kicad and just selected similar ones. I'm using the SH8M51 (https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/348/sh8m51gzetb-e-1873468.pdf)

Comment: OK, these should work. Do they burn while the electromagnet is on, or when turning it off? When turning it off, do you set both bottom FETs to ON to short it or let it discharge, or do you turn all the FETs OFF to dump the energy into the power supply? In this case, how much capacitance is there to prevent the voltage from rising to an unsafe value? Also are you sure there is no cross conduction?

Comment: Note the 2W number is when mounted on a ceramic board. They give 1.4W with 25x25mm copper to heat sink the pins. 0.6W in a SO8 would still need a bit of copper on the drain to act as a heat sink. If you don't have a copper pour to sink the heat, it'll get pretty toasty.

Comment: Actually, this circuit is just to switch the direction of the current. The current level is controlled by a low side N-Type MOSFET. So, the diagonal MOSFETs gates of the H-Bridge are connected and turned on or off. The energy goes therefore to the power supply for which I have no protection.
I'm not sure when exactly did they burn, but I assume they died when the load was turned off due to the high current peak.
I assume this solution is not ideal, as the MOSFETs are switched on or off all the time for a long period. That's because I suggested the use of Thyristors.

Comment: There's no problem in keeping a MOSFET ON continuously if the dissipation due to its RdsON is low enough to avoid overheating. I'm not sure this is the case here, because RdsON is quite high and SO-8 can't dissipate a lot of power without a large copper area on the pcb for heat sinking. Thyristors won't help, they'll burn more heat. IF the problem is overheating, then the solution is a lower RdsON FET and/or more heat sinking on the pcb.

Comment: Turning the load off doesn't make a current peak: the inductor will make a voltage spike on your power supply if there is not enough capacitance to absorb the energy in the inductor. That can cause overvoltage and blow the MOSFETs. There is also a spike in dissipation at MOSFET turn-off because the full inductor current runs through the MOSFET while it turns off. Switching too slowly and too often may cause this to blow the FET. Of course cross-conduction is also possible if the control signals don't have enough dead time.

Comment: Thank you, that's really useful information. I will try as you suggested to lower RdsON and/or more heat sinking on the pcb.

Comment: Yeah, but you should find out what the actual problem is (from the list of potential ones I mentioned) before fixing one or two of them

Comment: If your high side MOSFETs are N-type, you need floating power supplies for your high side drivers.

Comment: @winny you are right, but I'm using the method described here https://www.bristolwatch.com/ccs/power_mosfet_switch.htm that works also in this case if high speed switching is not required.

Comment: Oh, you are using high side P-channel. What Vgs do you measure during operation?

Comment: 80V for off-state and 65V for on-state thanks to the 15V zener diode

Comment: Did you see @bobflux' comment about the capacitances?  Are your "VDD" and "L-BH-" supplies each bypassed to ground (or to each other) with a big hefty capacitor?  When the inductor "spikes" that energy will flow thru the body diodes _and_then_get_stuck_ -- it will dump on the supply rails and they will "spike".  The inductor stores 0.5LI^2 = 72mJ of energy.  Dumped onto e.g. 100µF capacitor works out to 88.7V spike (i.e. enough to raise the 80V to 88.7V).  If you have NO capacitor, the spike is huge.  (FYI these calcs are all 0.5LI^2 and 0.5CV^2 energy calcs.)

Comment: Thank you @Atomique for your comment. That's a really good point.
I will try to calculate the required capacitor value and place one between VDD and L-BH-. There is no separate supplies, I mean, L-BH- is connected to GND through the N-type FET.
Thank you also for the formulas tho, it is always appreciated.
I found this snubber circuit that follows this idea I think: http://www.mcmanis.com/chuck/robotics/projects/esc2/hbridge_spiking.html

Comment: I found that the gate of the bottom N-type MOSFETs of the H-bridge are by default connected via a 1k resistor to GND. So, when I'm trying to set off the N-type MOSFETs I am creating a Vgs equal to the potential difference between GND and L-HB- (> 0V). This causes the bottom MOSFETs to be always either partially or totally on creating a shorting path and destroying them. In a real scenario I measured Vgs=2V when I thought the MOSFET was off.

Answer (score 3):

First of all, MOSFETs are good for your application - if used well.

IRF7309 seems rated for only 30V so I assume this name is just a placeholder.

In case the High-side FETs blow up, I can imagine it is because of their slow switching. They are turned on through a 120k resistor, which means there is only below 1 mA gate charge current. Say you need 10nC of gate charge, and you realize that the FET spends >10us in a highly dissipative turn-on phase. This will cause enormous switching power dissipation, especially when running at high currents.

Comment: You're right, the switching speed of the high side is really low.
Nevertheless, they are only used to switch the current direction as a N-type MOSFET is after the H-bridge that covers the switching part. 
If I want to switch the current direction, I cut the current flow to give enough time for the MOSFETs of the H-bridge for the transition. 
I will place this info also in the question, sorry for that.

Comment: @wellknow So does that mean the low side FETs burn ? Their switching is also pretty slow, so the same argument applies. 1k turn-off ideally and several 100 Ohm turn on ideally, is not really quick. It will be further worsened by the fact that optocouplers are slow things, not really suited for gate driving FETs in a hard-switched bridge.

Comment: I have a N-type MOSFET *after* the H-bridge (after Q1A and Q2A), so none of the MOSFETs of the H-bridge have to be switched quickly. They have to be tuned on/off every several seconds.

Comment: @wellknow Ok so you obviously have to post a schematic of your actual setup, before any of our answers can become helpful

Comment: Ok, I added a new image, I hope it is more understandable now.

Answer (score 1):

A number of things:

1. Did you calculate gate voltage rise/fall time?
2. Clamp diodes are superfluous: the intrinsic body diode serves the same purpose.
3. What is the ground return? If it's supposed to be switching, then Q1A-Q2A are effectively cascoded, but through feeble gate drive, neither of which seems a great idea.  To do it this way, you need a floating (referenced to source terminal) gate drive.  Better to just drive the low side with the switching (AND-gated with the polarity signal) and use a good enough gate driver in the first place.

Furthermore, we can gain additional efficiency by using the P-ch synchronously: instead of treating the H-bridge as a polarity control, treat it as two CMOS inverters.  Drive the left gates complementary (er, complementarily?), and the right.  Keep both sides high, or both sides low, by default to conserve current flow, and raise only the left or right side to make current increase or decrease.  Any old bootstrap gate driver will do, and P-ch is no longer necessary -- IR2101 and all N-ch's for instance.  A small shunt resistor in series with the two bottom sources affords current sense (note you can't do just one, else you'd miss the circulating current between the two when forcing it to 0V).

Comment: I added a more complete description of the circuit and a new image.
2. I added those diodes to protect the half-bridges, as the internal diodes can't carry so much current.

I understand your idea of only using N-type ones, the problem is that with a bootstrap gate drive I'm not able to turn the gates on for a long period of time as the bootstraping capacitor need to be charged again and again.

Comment: @wellknow FYI, MOSFETs can handle at least as much reverse current, as forward.  Basically thermally limited. Bootstrap can be solved by running slightly less than 100% duty cycle per side, or with a separate supply, or still using P-ch after all, with a somewhat improved drive circuit.